# Animating the color of document's body using jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to animate the color of the body of the page using jQuery:

Here is the code I've tried but it doesn't work and nothing changes at all?!

```
$(document.body).animate({ backgroundColor: '#32a852' }, 1500);
```

Am I missing something?

I tried to just change the body like this and it works fine:

```
$(document.body).css("background-color", "yellow");
```

Comment: Could you add the jsfiddle ?

Comment: https://codepen.io/pixy-dixy/pen/wvabjzq

Comment: For your first example to work you also need to include jQueryUI in the page: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/xst69qky/

Comment: @Rory McCrossan thanks that work in your code but I can't find a cdn for it...

Comment: Really? Literally first hit for 'jqueryui cdn'

Comment: Seems the problem was something else... I post another question..

Comment: Please have a look at the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61019860/overriding-background-color-of-the-body-tag-using-jquery-animation

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from https://api.jquery.com/animate/ :

"All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but **background-color** cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color plugin is used)."

So seems like you need to use JQuery.Color plugin.

Answer (score -1):

This works, I dont know what you are doing wrong
try this
$("body").animate({ backgroundColor: '#32a852' }, 1500);

Comment: I tested your code on any other web page.. it works

Comment: This doesn't work by itself. You need to include jQueryUI as well for it to work: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/xst69qky/