# Overriding background color of the body tag using jQuery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to animate the background of the `body` tag using jQuery:

So I've added the jQuery And jQuery UI CDNs and the code below:

```
$("body").animate({ backgroundColor: '#32a852' }, 1500);
```

The code works fine in JSFiddle But when I try to use it in my own code nothing changes!

Here is my body tag:

```
<body style="background: rgb(253, 253, 253);" class="cs-HTML is-theme-classic is-desktop" role="application"></body>
```

I think maybe the background color in the above body tag causes the problem and maybe we need to override this in some way...

I'm confused please help...

Comment: Check if `.is-theme-classic` adds a `background-color` with `!important`

Comment: Is there a any element that covers your body entirely?

Answer (score 0):

I added one jsfiddle u should take yout style to css and try again and u should be sure that body is full height and width and there is no override div full on body

> https://jsfiddle.net/9ycz5kus/2/

```
<body  class="cs-HTML is-theme-classic is-desktop" role="application"></body>

$("body").animate({backgroundColor: 'blue'},1500);

.cs-HTML {
  background: rgb(253, 253, 253);

}
```

Comment: Changing from inline to class based style doesn't solve OP's issue, and it states in the question that the results are seen in their jsfiddle, it doesn't work on their site